# How to add labels to sliderfield Sencha Touch

Tags: slider, sencha-touch

Ok, so I would like to have a slider that looks like this one.

Just can't figure out where we can at least have these delimiter separators? So if you see there are 7 delimiters and we have large labels on the first 4-th and the last delimeter.

How would you approach this task?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of adding a label inside sliderfield. However, you can indeed add HTML to acheive the required output. On the config panel, go to HTML property, and add something like this:

```
<div style="padding-left:1em">|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|<div>Low&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Average &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;High </div></div>
```

The output I have got:

[image]

You just need to playaround with the alignment of your text in the HTML. That will do!

Good Luck!

Comment: OMG, that I would consider a terrible bug for Sencha Touch UI

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather old question but I was faced with the very same need today. Building on GenieWanted's answer, I came to this:

```
...
    {
        xtype: 'sliderfield',
        maxValue: 5,
        label: 'Some data',
        html: '<table width="100%" align="left"><tr><td width="25%">Min</td><td width="50%" align="center">Med</td><td width="25%" align="right">Max</td></tr></table>'        
    }
...
```

which works very well for me, and avoids messing around to find the correct number of `&nbsp;` needed. Also, I suspect that results would vary from device to device using `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can create Custom Slider like this**

```
Ext.ns('Ext.ux');
Ext.ux.CustomSlider = Ext.extend(Object, {
    valueTextClass: 'x-slider-value-text',
    showSliderBothEndValue: true,
    sliderEndValueStyle: 'color: black',

    constructor: function(config){
        Ext.apply(this, config);
        Ext.ux.CustomSlider.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    init: function(parent) {
        var me = this;
        parent.on({
            painted: {
                fn: function(component) {
                    if (me.showSliderBothEndValue) me.showSliderEndValue(this);
                    if (!this.valueTextEl) {
                        this.valueTextEl = component.element.createChild({
                            cls: me.valueTextClass
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    },
    showSliderEndValue: function(slider) {
        var sliderPosX = slider.getComponent().getThumb().element.getX();
        var thumbHeight = slider.getComponent().getThumb().element.getHeight();
        var sliderLength = slider.getComponent().element.getWidth();
        var minValueEl = slider.getComponent().element.createChild();
        minValueEl.setHtml(slider.getComponent().getMinValue());
        minValueEl.applyStyles('overflow:hidden;position:absolute');
        minValueEl.applyStyles(this.sliderEndValueStyle);
        minValueEl.setLeft(14);
        minValueEl.setTop(thumbHeight -7);
        var maxValueEl = slider.getComponent().element.createChild();
        maxValueEl.setHtml(slider.getComponent().getMaxValue());
        maxValueEl.applyStyles('overflow:hidden;position:absolute');
        maxValueEl.applyStyles(this.sliderEndValueStyle);
        maxValueEl.setLeft(sliderLength-45);
        maxValueEl.setTop(thumbHeight - 7);
    }
});
```

**And create slider like this**

```
var slider = {
    xtype: 'sliderfield',
    flex : 6,
    label: "Percentage",
    name: "Percentage",
    value : 50,
    minValue : 0,
    maxValue : 100,
    labelWrap : true,
    labelAlign : 'left',
    increment : 10,
    plugins: [new Ext.ux.CustomSlider({
        showSliderBothEndValue: true
    })],
    listeners: {
        painted: function (slider) {
            var sliderPanelItems = this.parent.getInnerItems();
            sliderPanelItems[1].setValue(this.getValue());
        }, 
        change: function (me,slider, thumb, newVal, oldVal, opts) {
            var sliderPanelItems = this.parent.getInnerItems();
            sliderPanelItems[1].setValue(newVal);
      } 
    } 
};
```

**Result will be like this**

[image]

I did this using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/245717/Create-a-Plugin-to-Sencha-Touch-Ext-form-Slider-Cl) link